# facebook permission dialog not requesting all permission

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-login, facebook-permissions

i am facing wired problem.
i am logging in with facebook in my app. i am using
facebook's native  LoginButton. every thing is going fine when facebook app. is installed in deveice. and it is asking all permissions.

**now when facebook app. not installed in device, then it is not asking for all permission...!!!**

i am requesting for permissions by using

```
authButton.setReadPermissions(Arrays.asList("email", "public_profile", "user_location", "user_birthday", "user_friends", "user_likes", "user_work_history", "user_website", "user_about_me"));
```

**i have solved an issue of permission in dialog, by installing updated
'facebook-sdk'.**

now the problem is that permission dialog asking for all permissions, but now

**"user is getting null...!!!"**

while using

```
authButton.setSessionStatusCallback(new StatusCallback() {

    @Override
    public void call(final Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (session.isOpened()) {
            Request request = Request.newMeRequest(session, new Request.GraphUserCallback() {

                @Override
                public void onCompleted(GraphUser user, Response response) {
```

any help will be strongly appreciated...

Answer (score 1):

Whenever facebook application is already in device then, it will get permissions based on your login details in Facebook application.

But in case of without facebook application, they need verification of your application first,
Facebook API basically provide basic information primarily like public information, for extra permissions you have to register your application on [facebook developer site](https://developers.facebook.com), After verification you can get the rights to get user's all details from facebook for your application use.

There is My Apps tag on top of developer site of the facebook, then you have to register your self as developer, after then you have to add your application name and application SHA code with screen shots on the facebook developer site.

With in a week you will get response from facebook developer, and you will get rights for permissions, if all going well.

This is my experience while integrate facebook with my application.

Comment: i already done all this and i already approved all permissions.